# Tkinter grid and widget size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am actually learning Tkinter and I want to do a window looking like this (tetris GUI) : 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsqPG.jpg)
So I want to do a 20x15 grid (h x w) with a tile size of 25px (so 500px x 375px playArea size) 
So here is the code I made :

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

# PLAYAREA SIZE
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = HEIGHT // 2
TILE_SIZE = 25

playarea = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='yellow')
playarea.grid(column=6, row=0, columnspan=WIDTH // TILE_SIZE, rowspan=HEIGHT // TILE_SIZE)


menuFrame=Frame(root, width=(WIDTH // 2), height=HEIGHT).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan= (WIDTH // 2) // TILE_SIZE , rowspan= int(HEIGHT / TILE_SIZE))
newGameButton = Button(menuFrame, text='Start', width= 75 , height = 1 * TILE_SIZE)
newGameButton.grid(column=1, row=1,columnspan=3, rowspan= 1)
newTestButton = Button(menuFrame, text='Test', width= 5 * TILE_SIZE, height = 1* TILE_SIZE)
newTestButton.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=5, rowspan=1)
root.update()

print(newGameButton.winfo_width())
print(playarea.grid_size())
#print(playarea.grid_info())

root.mainloop()
```

I use HEIGHT and WIDTH variables to define the size of my canvas and my TILE_SIZE variable to define te amount of tile is needed (to configure **columnspan** and **rowspan**) my first problem is that my :

```
print(playarea.grid_size())
```

Return (0,0), as I configured columnspan and rowspan it should return me (10,20), no ?

Then the other one issue is with my buttons, here I created two buttons (newGame and test), I want the newGame to be 75px wide (or 3 * TILE_SIZE) but when I run it (for both of width = 75 and width = 3 * TILE_SIZE) the

```
print(newGameButton.winfo_width())
```

Return me 617px and the button is huge, I don't understand why, can someone explain how grid works ? What's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `print(playarea.grid_size())`
>
> Return (0,0), as I configured columnspan and rowspan it should return me (10,20), no ?

No. `grid_size` returns the size (number of rows and columns) of the grid. This is how the computation of the value is made, according to the official tcl/tk documentation:

*"The size is determined either by the slave occupying the largest row or column, or the largest column or row with a minsize, weight, or pad that is non-zero."*

In your specific case you've only put widgets in row 0, column 0, so the reported size of `(0,0)` is correct.

> `print(newGameButton.winfo_width())`
>
> Return me 617px and the button is huge, I don't understand why, can someone explain how grid works ? What's causing this.

When you create a button with text but no image, the `width` is interpreted as a number of *characters* rather than *pixels*.

Comment: Thank you ! "When you create a button with text but no image, the width is interpreted as a number of characters rather than pixels. " I would have never found this by myself, what's the best way to size the button then ? Knowing font size and spacing then setting the size, or is there another way ?

Comment: @Rikougo: there are several ways. The easiest is to give it a 1x1 pixel image along with the text (and remember to define the `compound` option). Personally, though, if they are text buttons you shouldn't be specifying an exact pixel size if you expect to be able to run the program on more than one machine. Let tkinter decide how wide it should be to fit the text.